# How do I replace the deprecated "Attribute Mix" node from 2.93 in blender 3.3

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, custom-attributes

How do I replace the deprecated *Attribute Mix* node from 2.93 in blender 3.3 using a vertex group *as a kind of falloff* for the scale of distributed instances on points.

I am trying to follow/replicate Jayanam's 2021 tutorial https://youtu.be/yl2dtMbI--k?t=475
I almost finished it, except the 2 min. part.

The first screenshot below came from the original scene in v.2.93 and the second is where I am stuck in 3.3. Since there is no *Attribute Mix* node anymore I couldn't figure that out despite many tries... Any help or direction appreciated.

[image: Geo nodes in blender v. 2.93]
[image: Geo nodes in blender v. 3.3]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273541/145249

Comment: yes thanks I've seen this but still not easy to interpret those for a beginner like me. Actually watching  _Overview of Node Changes in Blender 3.0_  now https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254871/overview-of-node-changes-in-blender-3-0

Comment: The `Attribute Mix` node has been replaced by the [Mix](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/color/mix_rgb.html) node.

Comment: Yes I know but where do I _connect_ a vertex group and a scale attribue there ? That's were I am lost...

Comment: You don't really need a `Mix` node here (this node actually mixes two vectors/RGB-values), you would just have to use the math node `Multiply` and multiply the value of `Random Value` by the factor (or vertex group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have now rebuilt this for you in version *3.3*, and the solution should look like this:

[image]

Here I use instead of the node `Attribute Mix` the node `Mix`.

By the way, in Blender 3.2 and 3.3 this node is called `MixRGB` and is located in the *Color* category. In Blender 3.4 there is an additional new node that explicitly mixes values. This is called `Mix` and is located in the category *Utilities*.

[image]

Alternatively, as already mentioned in the comments, you can directly multiply the value of the vertex group with the randomly generated value of `Random Value`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Wow ! Many thanks for everything! I've learned a lot ! I missed totally the _Name_Attribute_ node too... now I have something weird in my scene with the VertexWeightProximity modifier and Lowest/Highest settings because my scale is I guess different, but I will figured that out.